# Ubuntu 12.10 Ubuntu-Guest and VirtualBox(Windows) host

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtualbox DNS stopped working on upgrade to 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204953/virtualbox-dns-stopped-working-on-upgrade-to-12-10)

The internet connection on the Windows Guest is not working. It is set on NAT. Incidentally this was working on 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Set the internet connection as Bridged. It should work fine. and check that the IPs are correct.

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining "How"

Comment: What do you mean by checking that IPs are correct? Do you mean that the bridged adapter should have the same IP / DNS as in the host?

Comment: Nopes, this Bridged thing is not working!

Comment: Have you tried switching the setting the virtual adapter as bridged?? In the case of IPs, i mean that you should assign an ip in your network. Not the same IP.

Comment: Have you installed virtualbox guest additions in your windows guest?

Comment: Yes! All things, as mentioned earlier, were configured, installed and working. I was using the NAT. However, as suggested by you, the Bridged Adapter is not working as well.

Comment: Well, it appears that one has to take the following steps:

<ol><li>VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
<li>VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnsproxy1 on</ol>

and the problem will be solved!