# How do I set up internet connection in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

This question is not duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204953/virtualbox-dns-stopped-working-on-upgrade-to-12-10), because in my case, internet connection doesn't work on any version of Ubuntu as host (11.04, 12.04,.12.10), and the solution is different too, mine needed VirtualBox and extension pack from official website, not from USC, and it solved the problem.

Here is the question:

I downloaded VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software Center and had installed Lubuntu and Windows XP inside VirtualBox. Both are connected via NAT, I have tried other options too, but none of them works.

How do I share internet from host OS to guest OS? I'm using USB modem mobile broadband connection on host OS (Ubuntu Quantal).

I have read [No internet connectivity in virtual-box with both Host and Virtual OS being 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143776/no-internet-connectivity-in-virtual-box-with-both-host-and-virtual-os-being-12-0), but still I don't know what to do. Can you give me step-by-step solution?

Comment: Did you install guest additions?

Comment: @Mitch Yes I have installed it because I need shared folder.

Comment: @BrandonLaizure I have searched in google before asking this question, and there is no specific solution for my question (Ubuntu and Windows as guest and Ubuntu as host)

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Comment: I have no technical knowledge to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to virtual box official web page, and then downlaod and install extension pack for version of vb you using now. then just simply when it is installed, go to settings, and usder usb submenu enable usb connection, and leave NAT as it is.

Comment: I'm using version 4.1.18 from USC, there is no extension pack for my version on official site.

Comment: i suggest you oracle virtual box as linux official product

Comment: I downloaded official virtualbox and extension and it works like a charm now, thanks!